# Why are angled brackets in my string being output incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulties with angled brackets in a string. I'm trying to have a file output, but apparently I don't know how to handle this. To be fair, I'm at a knuckle-dragging level with all this, so my vernacular is probably wrong (I'm a writer/visual designer; code ain't my thing).

Basically, if something is in angled brackets, I encounter one of a few problems:

- It adds ="" at the end of the words in the angled bracket if there is more than one word in the angled brackets.
- It adds the  end tag if it doesn't already exist.
- If  is in the file, it removes the  portion.

I experimented with using &gt and &lt in place of < and > to see if that would fix things, but then it would just literally use "&gt" and "&lt."

I'm using this:

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

To try and turn something like this:

```
"#\n# Configuration stuff below\n# (Based on buttons selected)\n#\n\n Single word items in tags like <this> create another instance of the item as if to close it manually.\n";
"\n\n <extension type>\n Two words in an tag results in added characters.\n </extension>";
"\n\n <input type>\n Use of the word \"input\" in a tag makes the closing tag straight up vanish.\n </input>";
```

...into something like this:

```
#
# Configuration stuff below
# (Based on buttons selected)
#

Single word items in tags like <this> create another instance of the item as if to close it manually.

 <extension type>
 Two words in an tag results in added characters.
 </extension>

 <input type>
 Use of the word "input" in a tag makes the closing tag straight up vanish.
 </input>
```

But instead, I'm getting this:

```
#
# Configuration stuff below
# (Based on buttons selected)
#

 Single word items in tags like <this> create another instance of the item as if to close it manually.
</this>

 <extension type="">
 Two words in an tag results in added characters.
 </extension>

 <input type="">
 Use of the word "input" in a tag makes the closing tag straight up vanish.
```

A stripped-down version of what I'm attempting is here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PoYGmpo

What's the best way of correcting the issue with the items in tags (short of going back in time and turning my arts degree into something more functional)?

Comment: Instead of combining those pieces of text in a `var`, you're adding them to `.innerHTML` of a `<textarea>`. That will parse them as HTML. Just use `var text = base;` then add to it: `text += nxpdb;` then finally `return text;`. Now call the function like `var text = compile();` in your click handler.

Comment: Or just replace every occurrence of `.innerHTML` with `.textContent` and you can use your code as-is.

Comment: @Chris - I guess I can't upvote answers yet, but I wanted to say thank you. Both solutions you mentioned worked, and it was incredibly useful to have two different approaches to learn from. It helped me mentally contextualize things much better as well. I really appreciate the help!